# C# multiple strings with line breaks in between into one TextAreaFor field (MVC)

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, string-formatting

I have 3 strings that have the following format(each on its own line):

"String 1"

"String 2"

"String 3"

What's the best way to recreate/transfer this format into a textareafor in my view (while still binding to a viewmodel property)?

Comment: css... not really sure what you are asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

that will be passed to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var strings = new[] { "String 1", "String 2", "String 3" };
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, strings)
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

for rendering:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the strings in a IList that belongs to the viewmodel.